# Solution of Wave Equation using Reflection Principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations

A sample problem for an exam is as follows:

> Consider the wave equation $U_{tt} = 4U_{xx}, 0 < x < 1$ with $U(0,t)= U(l,t)= 0$ and $U(x,0)= x(1-x)$, $U_t(x,0)= \pi$.
>
> Find $U(1/4,1/4)$ and $U(1/2,1/2)$ using the reflection principle.

We went over the solution in lecture but I lost my notes and I'm unsure how to proceed.  If someone could provide a solution with some explanation I would greatly appreciate it.

Note: $U_x$ and $U_t$ denote the partial derivative with respect to $x$ or $t$ respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reflection method consists in extending the problem to $\mathbb R\times [0,\infty)$ in such a way that the given boundary condition $u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0$ becomes a consequence of some symmetry of initial conditions $u(\cdot, 0)=g$ and $u_t(\cdot, 0)=h$. In order to make sure that there is no motion at $x=0$, we need $g(-x)=-g(x)$ and $h(-x)=-h(x)$. Similarly, to fix the point at $x=1$ we need $g(2-x)=-g(x)$ and $h(2-x)=-h(x)$. Thus, both $g$ and $h$ are $2$-periodic functions. Their period from $-1$ to $1$ is shown below: red is the initial position $g$, blue is the velocity $h$.

[image: Initial data]

Now it remains to apply [d'Alembert's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula) with propagation speed $c=2$. 
$$u(x,t) = \frac12 (g(x-2t) + g(x+2t)) + \frac{1}{4} \int_{x-2t}^{x+2t} h(s)\,ds$$
The piecewise nature of $g$ and $h$ would make it awkward to write out these integrals in general, but it's not hard to evaluate them at particular points $(x,t)$, which is what you asked to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [reference](http://maths.swan.ac.uk/staff/vl/pdes-course.pdf) where the method is explained in detailes. Starting on page $19$.

Comment: That reference isn't helpful, because while the spatial domain of the problem stated by rmh52 is $x \in [0,\ell]$, the spatial domain in the reference is $x \in [0,\infty)$.

Comment: @rlgordonma The reference is at least somewhat helpful, because the method can be adapted to bounded intervals. I posted an answer.

Comment: Perhaps.  But it just seems that the problem is more naturally solved by Fourier decomposition, which is more or less equivalent to your formulation.

Comment: @rlgordonma If you wanted a general formula for $U(x,t)$, the Fourier series is a natural tool indeed. Here we just want a numeric value of $U(1/4,1/4)$, which according to my answer is $\frac{1}{2}(g(-1/4)+g(3/4))+\frac14 \int_{-1/4}^{3/4} h = 0 +\frac14 (\pi/2)=\pi/8$. Compare this effort with expanding $x(1-x)$ into a Fourier series, and then trying to sum the infinite series back to find what $U(1/4,1/4)$ actually is.

Comment: @PavelM: Thanks for replying to his comment.