# Cauchy problem. I can't resolve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please help me to do this Cauchy problem: $xy'+y=y^2 \ln x$  , $x>0$; $y(1)=1$

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you encounter a Bernoulli equation  $$y'+p(x)y=y^nq(x)$$ you can solve the following first linear OE instead: $$u'+(1-n)p(x)u=(1-u)q(x), u=y^{1-n}$$ In your OE, first divide both sides of it by $x$. We have $x>0$ so: $$y'+\frac{1}{x}y=\frac{\ln x}{x}y^2$$ Here $n=2$, $p(x)=1/x, q(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$ so we have $$u'-\frac{1}{x}u=-\frac{\ln x}{x},x>0$$ So we have $$d\left(\frac{1}{x}u\right)=-\frac{\ln x}{x^2},x>0$$. Hope you can solve the rest. First find $u$ and second find $y$.

Comment: like it!!!!!!!!!!!+1

Answer (score 2):

here is picture,which can help you  to solve it, so[image]lve it

Comment: Is this just a copy and paste from Wolfram|Alpha? At the very least, you could have taken the time to write the text yourself, or link to Wolfram|Alpha, or at a minimum, cite W|A as your source.

Comment: Nothing wrong with Copy n Paste, no need to reinvent the wheel for already solved out problems. though a source would surely be nice.

Comment: yes .it is  copy,unfortunately i have not time,but about  link i should note that,when i  try to open it,it asked me about  wolfram ID,so if i  put link,author of this question could not  open it without  register here,so i simplified it